# Why does dragging (drop/drag) element cause dropzone (div) to partially disappear?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

Using HTML5 Drag/Drop, when dragging element the dropzone partially disappears from UI, as seen in screenshot. The partial missing div in the image has a red boarder.  When I remove the "hr" tag, from the code below, it works and the div does NOT disappear when dragging element!  This is only happening in Chrome browser.  All the code is below.  Does anyone know why this is occurring?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title></title>

<style>
    .objects {
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #FFF3CC;
        border: #DFBC6A 1px solid;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 8px;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;
        cursor: move;
    }

    #drop_zone {
        background-color: #EEE;
        border: #f00 1px solid;
        width: 280px;
        height: 200px;
        padding: 8px;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
</style>

<script>
        function _(id){
           return document.getElementById(id);
        }
        var droppedIn = false;
        function drag_start(event) {

             _('app_status').innerHTML = "Dragging the " + 
event.target.getAttribute('id');

            event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
            event.dataTransfer.setData("text", 
event.target.getAttribute('id') );
        }
        function drag_enter(event) {
            _('app_status').innerHTML = "You are dragging over the 
"+event.target.getAttribute('id');
        }
        function drag_leave(event) {
            _('app_status').innerHTML = "You left the 
"+event.target.getAttribute('id');
        }
        function drag_drop(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); /* Prevent undesirable default behavior 
while dropping */
            var elem_id = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
            event.target.appendChild( _(elem_id) );
            _('app_status').innerHTML = "Dropped "+elem_id+" into the 
"+event.target.getAttribute('id');
            _(elem_id).removeAttribute("draggable");
            _(elem_id).style.cursor = "default";
            droppedIn = true;
        }
        function drag_end(event) {
            if(droppedIn == false){
                _('app_status').innerHTML = "You let the 
"+event.target.getAttribute('id')+" go.";
            }
            droppedIn = false;
        }
        function readDropZone(){
    alert('dropzone');
            for(var i=0; i < _("drop_zone").children.length; i++){
                alert(_("drop_zone").children[i].id+" is in the drop zone");
            }
            /* Run Ajax request to pass any data to your server */
        }
</script>

</head>
<body>

<h2 id="app_status">App status...</h2>

<h1>Drop Zone</h1>

<div id="drop_zone" ondragenter="drag_enter(event)" 
ondrop="drag_drop(event)" ondragover="return false" 
ondragleave="drag_leave(event)"></div>
<div id="object1" class="objects" draggable="true" 
ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="drag_end(event)">object 1</div>
<div id="object2" class="objects" draggable="true" 
ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="drag_end(event)">object 2</div>
<div id="object3" class="objects" draggable="true" 
ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="drag_end(event)">object 3</div>

<hr />
<br />
<button onclick="readDropZone()">Get Object Data</button>


</body>
</html>
```

[image: DIV display cut off]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my tests, even if I deleted the `<hr />`, the error was still reproduced. I noticed, that it occurs after changing `h2#app_status` text. If you wrap `div#drop_zone` and all next elements like `div#object...` with div that has `inline-block` as display style, then there will be no such disappearing.

```
<style>
   #drop-zone-wrapper {display: inline-block;}
</style>

<div id="drop-zone-wrapper">
    <div id="drop_zone" ondragenter="drag_enter(event)"
         ondrop="drag_drop(event)" ondragover="return false"
         ondragleave="drag_leave(event)"></div>
    <div id="object1" class="objects" draggable="true"
         ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="drag_end(event)">object 1</div>
    <div id="object2" class="objects" draggable="true"
         ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="drag_end(event)">object 2</div>
    <div id="object3" class="objects" draggable="true"
         ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="drag_end(event)">object 3</div>
</div>
```